# I don't know the authentication password

Tags: updates

I am new to Ubuntu, and I just installed it. When I update, an authentication password is asked, but I don't know what password it is that I should enter.

Comment: Its your password. The password you used to log in with.

Answer (score 0):

It is the password you set when you installed Ubuntu and the password you log in with.

Answer (score 0):

when you installed Ubuntu you created a user and you set a password for it and verify it when it ask for authentication it only ask for that user password